# syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php, sql, if

Qual o erro?

```
$sql = "SELECT item1, item2, item3 FROM tab_exemplo WHERE" 
if (isset($item3)) {echo 'quartos LIKE :A';}
if (isset($item2) || isset($item1) || isset($item4)){echo 'AND'}
if (isset($item4)){echo 'garagens LIKE :B';}
if (isset($item2) || isset($item1) || isset($item3)){echo 'AND'}
if (isset($item2)){echo 'tipoNegocio LIKE :C';}
if (isset($item3) || isset($item1) || isset($item4)){echo 'AND'}
if (isset($item1)){echo 'tipo LIKE :D';} echo '\"';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Procure organizar melhor seu código que evitará erros simples assim. Note abaixo como fica mais fácil ler e localizar problemas no código. Faltam `;`  na finalização de várias linhas.

Acostume-se também interpretar as mensagens de erro e procurar na documentação sobre eles. Em programação erros acontecem aos montes. Se sempre que aparecer um tiver que perguntar pata alguém ficar lento e cansativo programar.

Muitas vezes o erro aparece em um lugar mas está em outro. O compilador/interpretador não consegue entender intenção. Se falta um ponto e vírgula que encerra o comando, então o erro só vai aparecer na linha seguinte quando encontrar algo estranho no que ele considera ainda o meio do comando (embora você programador tinha a intenção que fosse um comando novo).

Montar expressões SQL assim podem ser temerárias em termos de segurança dependendo de onde vem essas variáveis.

No comentário foi mencionado que seria para concatenar *strings*. Mesmo que o problema colocado na pergunta fosse esse, ainda teria que mudar muita coisa. Não só teria que concatenar a variável `$sql` no lugar de usar `echo`, mas também precisa rever a organização do texto já que desta forma não produziria uma consulta correta. Também acho estranho a forma de determinação do que deve concatenar.

Comment: tá certo porém gostaria de concatenar os echo´s junto com as strings do SELECT portanto não poderia colocar ; depois do where

Comment: O `;` nada tem a ver com concatenação, esse é outro problema. Se você quer concatenar, então concatene, mas não deixe de encerrar o comando. Parece um jeito confuso de concatenar. Principalmente usando `echo`. Se vai concatenar tem que usar a variável, não imprimir o texto.

Comment: exatamente isso, obrigado!